# Laravel load balanced site Auth is null when making ajax call

Tags: ajax, laravel, authentication, load-balancing

Ok, so we're using a load balancer in front of two servers that host s single Laravel site.

Loading pages and controllers actions and things work perfectly fine when using straight blade -> controller -> db paths. But we have a couple places that make ajax calls from a vue app section of the codebase. Those call all fail.

Every time we make an ajax call, the resulting controller has `Auth::user()` as null. It's like the session isn't recognized in the controllers called from ajax requests. But the controllers called directly from routes work just fine.

Any thoughts on what could be our issue?

Comment: Are these routes using web middleware?  Is session shared between servers?  What session store is it?

Comment: Added an answer, yea it was the api middleware that was the resulting issue. The cause were routes placed in the wrong location.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it was poor web/api design. Some api routes were in `api.php` route file but they should have been in the `web.php` route file. They're just an app backend called by the api, not a true rest api. They were very much stateful routes and the api middleware did not like that.